# Android - Change RelativeLayout to Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to "remake" my app.
I already write an app and it works OK. But, it use Activity and Spinner to switch between screens - that is too uncomfortable and slow. 
I here find an example of Fragment usage for user-comfortable usage and fast switching beetween screens with swiping:
http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views

But I cant set RelativeLayout for it from my app, because it use Fragment.
Is there a way to "copy-paste" the markup file (*.xml) without making fundamental changes in the application?

I tried to do it (the commented line of code), but it does not work.

**FirstTab.java**

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FirstTab extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /*View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_first, container, false);
        Button imageView = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_quit);
        return view;*/

        TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
        tv.setText("First Tab");
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tv.setWidth(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        tv.setHeight(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        tv.setTextAppearance(getActivity(),android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
        return tv;
    }
}
```

**first_tab.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
    android:paddingTop="5sp"
    android:paddingRight="5sp"
    android:paddingLeft="5sp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <Spinner
        android:entries="@array/activity_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_quit"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_quit"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_quit"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Close\napp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/btn_quit"
        android:onClick="quit"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_quit"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/eng_text"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:hint="Enter text"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect|textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="7"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eng_text"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/morse_text"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:hint="Get a code"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect|textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="8" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Translate"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/trans_btn"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_sound"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="translate"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|bottom"
        android:text="Play\ncode:"
        android:id="@+id/play_label"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/trans_btn"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_sound"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_sound" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_sound"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_flash"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_flash"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:onClick="play_sound"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_flash"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/view"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:onClick="play_flash"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Current input\nlanguage:"
        android:id="@+id/cur_lang"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/trans_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_flag"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cur_lang"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cur_lang"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cur_lang"
        android:enabled="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: First two screenshoots - what I have; Third - what I want to do]

Comment: First two screenshoots - app, using Spinner for switching;
Third - you can swipe between tabs. Help me to set my layout to tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to convert your whole three activities to fit into a single page using view pager

1. Make a new Activity with root tag a android.supprot.v4.ViewPager
2. Set up the adapter and all the other things
3. In your first tab use the following code

   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_first, container, false);

   ```
       Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_quit);
       button.setText("Working quit");
       return view;
   ```

   }

use view to access any of the elements of first_tab

Comment: Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_quit); ---- thanks a lot!
This save a lot of time for me!

Comment: your welcome if you are using functions in the fragment pass view so that you can use views in that fuctions itself

Comment: Yes, I know it. Works like in case of Activity, but:

Comment: Button new_game = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);  -- for activity
Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_quit); --- for view (ViewPager).

That was the reason, why it crased.